# How to install glm-math on ubuntu 16.04? glm 0.9.9~a2-2

Tags: ubuntu, glm-math

this is probably really simple but I have downloaded the proper package for glm, glm-0.9.9-a2,  but I do not know how to install. Instructions were either too complex or too simple.

I was not able to find the package by using a package manager or a way to add the repository to either aptitude or Anaconda. So, I downloaded the tar.gz file and extracted it.

Suggestions?

Thank You
Tom

Answer (score 8):

If you want to install the library on Ubuntu, the package is libglm-dev,

```
sudo apt install libglm-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you download the .zip or .7zip version from the [glm site's download section](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/tags), then find the folder named `glm`(the one in the same location as the `CMkaeLists.txt` and `readme.md`), copy it and paste it to the location where you put your header files which are added to your projects.